# How to get all commits for a certain release in GitHub?

Tags: java, github, github-api

I know I can get all **commits** in a **project** using `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits`

Now I want to get all **commits** for a certain **release** of that **project**.

What should I do?

Comment: Define what associates a commit with a release? Do you want the commits between releases or all commits before the one on which a release was tagged?

Comment: Hi sigmavirus24,such like these commits :[github](https://github.com/nasa/mct/compare/v1.8b3...master)

Comment: So you want commits *since* some release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your answer to my question, you want the commits made **since** some tag. This will take a couple steps to complete, first you need to get the SHA for the tag in question. You'll want to use the [git references API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/) to [get a specific reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#get-a-reference). In the specific example that you linked you'll want to do

```
GET /repos/nasa/mct/git/refs/tags/v1.8b3
```

And you'll want to get the 'sha' attribute from the object stored in the 'object' attribute of the response object. With the 'sha' attribute, you'll want to use the [commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) to [list commits starting with that 'sha'](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) so your request will look like this:

```
GET /repos/nasa/mct/commits?sha=%(sha_from_first_request)s
```

That will give you 30 commits per-page by default (if I remember correctly), so you should see if adding `&per_page=100` to the end helps. I can't tell you exactly how to do this in Java, but I expect you'll be able to use one of the [libraries written to interact with the API](https://developer.github.com/libraries/) to make it easier.

Comment: I appreciate your method,this should be a solution.Thank you !